# Integration: x-values that make an equation true

Tags: calculus

If $\ln x=\int^x_1 \frac{1}{t}dt$, what are all the possible values of $x$ that make the equation true? The domain of $\ln x$ is $x>0$ but on the right side of the equation, $x$ must be $\geq 1$. So the range of x-values that make the equation true is $\geq 1$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the RHS, the integral bound can be $x<1$ as well. In fact, it could be even negative as long as $x\ne 0$.

For instance, for $x<0$,

$$\int^x \frac{1}{t}dt = \int^{-x} \frac{1}{u}du= \ln(-x)+ C$$

Comment: Is this because the RHS can be rewritten as an integral with the bounds switched and a negative in front of the integral, in which case $x\leq 1$

Comment: Correct. It happens in variable substitutions all the time

Comment: Wait but how can $x$ be negative. That makes the natural log undefined.

Comment: For $x < 0$ the integral is improper and diverges.

Comment: I still don’t get why x can be less than zero. The natural log doesn’t allow for this.

Comment: As an integral expression on the RHS, $x$ could be any #. This is a general statement for RHS. But, for negative $x$, the LHS would be a difference result, as illustrated in the example. Sorry, for the confusion: I did not mean you equality is still true in such case.

Comment: So x>0 would be the acceptable x values for my original equation?

Comment: That is correct